# Break or New line

Tags: c#, wpf, ellipse, wrappanel

I have a control with an `Ellipse` inside and I insert this control to `WrapPanel` dynamically with foreach. Does anyone know how can I separate some `Ellipse` from the others with **Break** or **Newline**:

```
foreach (var system in provider.Systems)
{
    foreach (var fx in system.Fxes)
    {
        panel1.Children.Add(TrunkControl());
    }

    panel1.Children.Add(new SeperatorControl());
}
```

I want to add a new line or break after inner foreach. I just don't know what my `SeperatorControl` should be.

Comment: what do you mean by separate? add a gap between them?

Comment: I want to add some Ellipse, then go to next line and add some other Ellipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add all your Ellipse to another `StackPanel` then add that to your main `StackPanel`

so panel1 will be set to Vertical and you will add new StackPanels with all the Ellipse , there is no such thing as a new line in a stack panel.

```
        foreach (var system in provider.Systems)
        {
            var stackpanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
            foreach (var fx in system.Fxes)
            {
                stackpanel.Children.Add(TrunkControl());
            }
            panel1.Children.Add(stackpanel); 
        }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but this is not work for me. I want to add some circles, then go to the next line and add some other circles. do you have any idea?

Comment: does each line have the same amount of circles? can you post a picture of what you want, or your foreach loop

Comment: TrunkControl() is your elipse's, what is SeperatorControl ?

Comment: Yes, trunkControl is for ellipse, SeperatorControl is a control taht i want to add a break for me! but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Yes, but i used WrapPanel instead of StackPanel.